# Does it make sense to use a nipple to connect a tub spout to copper?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub, spout

I recently purchased a Grohe tub spout and it requires a MNPT fitting on the copper. The MNPT fitting must be placed behind the CBU and the tolerance is 1/8". Since I haven't chosen my tile yet, I'm still not sure how long to cut the copper pipe.

My question is: can I just sweat on another female npt fitting on the copper in the wall, then just make a smaller intermediate pipe with two male ends (basically a copper nipple)? I'm just thinking that way, I can cut the intermediate copper pipe & screw it in after the cbu and tile is done.

Here's a diagram of what I'm thinking:

[image: diagram of spout fitting]

Here's the spout in question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pc0r.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use a [copper sweat by FIP 90° elbow](https://www.boone.ca/en/products/pipe-valves-and-fittings/copper-brass-pipe-fittings/1-2-wing-back-90-elbow-c-x-fpt-copper-cast-pressure/) (often called a wing back elbow, as it has tabs on it to allow for securing to backing). Then screw in a [test nipple](http://www.lyncar.com/plumbing/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=1407) (or use a nipple and cap) while the tile is being done. Once tile is done, use a [brass nipple](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Brass-Nipples-163000) of the correct length (best to buy a few of different lengths and just return the ones that were the wrong length).

Answer (score 0):

You can but, I would get a spout for copper. They clamp on with an Allen wrench. More connections = possible leaks. Also when removing the spout it could all come out with it (not a big deal). Make sure everything is copper. Galvanized pipe leaves rust stains.